# Error when compiling gwt project that uses Errai framework

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jboss, errai

I have a project with multiple gwt modules. Some of these modules depends on other modules, so I have to `inherit` the dependencies in my `gwt.xml`. In one of these modules I had an issue that When I `inherit` other dependencies modules I created it would throw the exception similar to the following exception:

```
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:112)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:86)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator.startAsyncGeneratorsAndWaitFor(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:100)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:58)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:355)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JTryStatement.traverse(JTryStatement.java:60)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO] Compiling module module.ui.widget.desktop.Desktop
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper'
[INFO]       Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]          Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:900)
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error generating BootstrapperImpl
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:625)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:640)
[INFO] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException:  @> module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
[INFO]  - field org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField:module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter.shellView could not be satisfied for type: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
[INFO]   Message: can't resolve bean: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView ( @Any  @Default )
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO] 
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:112)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:86)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator.startAsyncGeneratorsAndWaitFor(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:100)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:58)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
[ERROR] Caused by: org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException:  @> module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
[ERROR]  - field org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField:module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter.shellView could not be satisfied for type: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView
[ERROR]   Message: can't resolve bean: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView ( @Any  @Default )
[ERROR] 
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException.createWithSingleFieldFailure(UnsatisfiedDependenciesException.java:39)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.api.InjectionTask.doTask(InjectionTask.java:119)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil.handleInjectionTasks(InjectUtil.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil.access$000(InjectUtil.java:72)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:355)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil$2.generateConstructor(InjectUtil.java:150)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.basic.TypeInjector.renderProvider(TypeInjector.java:140)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor$3.handle(IOCConfigProcessor.java:411)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor$7.process(IOCConfigProcessor.java:650)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor.process(IOCConfigProcessor.java:596)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator.generateBootstrappingClassSource(IOCBootstrapGenerator.java:283)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator.generate(IOCBootstrapGenerator.java:139)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:68)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator$1.call(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:43)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator$1.call(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[ERROR]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JTryStatement.traverse(JTryStatement.java:60)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:900)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:625)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:640)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
[INFO] Caused by: org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException:  @> module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter
[INFO]  - field org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField:module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter.shellView could not be satisfied for type: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView
[INFO]   Message: can't resolve bean: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView ( @Any  @Default )
[INFO] 
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException.createWithSingleFieldFailure(UnsatisfiedDependenciesException.java:39)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.api.InjectionTask.doTask(InjectionTask.java:119)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil.handleInjectionTasks(InjectUtil.java:163)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil.access$000(InjectUtil.java:72)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.InjectUtil$2.generateConstructor(InjectUtil.java:150)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.injector.basic.TypeInjector.renderProvider(TypeInjector.java:140)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor$3.handle(IOCConfigProcessor.java:411)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor$7.process(IOCConfigProcessor.java:650)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCConfigProcessor.process(IOCConfigProcessor.java:596)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator.generateBootstrappingClassSource(IOCBootstrapGenerator.java:283)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator.generate(IOCBootstrapGenerator.java:139)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:68)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator$1.call(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator$1.call(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JTryStatement.traverse(JTryStatement.java:60)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:900)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:625)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:640)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.searchForTypeBySource(UnifyAst.java:981)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.access$1500(UnifyAst.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:364)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  ... 45 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(62): GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class)
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(62): (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class)
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(62): final Bootstrapper bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class)
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(46): {
[INFO]   Container.init = false;
[INFO]   QualifierUtil.initFromFactoryProvider(new Container$1(this));
[INFO]   LogUtil.log("IOC bootstrapper successfully initialized.");
[INFO]   if (((IOCEnvironment) new IOCEnvironmentImpl()).isAsync()) {
[INFO]     LogUtil.log("bean manager initialized in async mode.");
[INFO]   }
[INFO]   final Bootstrapper bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class);
[INFO]   Container.injectionContext = bootstrapper.bootstrapContainer();
[INFO]   final CreationalContext rootContext = Container.injectionContext.getRootContext();
[INFO]   if (rootContext instanceof AsyncCreationalContext) {
[INFO]     ((AsyncCreationalContext) rootContext).finish(new Container$2(this));
[INFO]   } else {
[INFO]     ((SimpleCreationalContext) rootContext).finish();
[INFO]     this.finishInit();
[INFO]   }
[INFO] }
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(46): try {
[INFO]   Container.init = false;
[INFO]   QualifierUtil.initFromFactoryProvider(new Container$1(this));
[INFO]   LogUtil.log("IOC bootstrapper successfully initialized.");
[INFO]   if (((IOCEnvironment) new IOCEnvironmentImpl()).isAsync()) {
[INFO]     LogUtil.log("bean manager initialized in async mode.");
[INFO]   }
[INFO]   final Bootstrapper bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class);
[INFO]   Container.injectionContext = bootstrapper.bootstrapContainer();
[INFO]   final CreationalContext rootContext = Container.injectionContext.getRootContext();
[INFO]   if (rootContext instanceof AsyncCreationalContext) {
[INFO]     ((AsyncCreationalContext) rootContext).finish(new Container$2(this));
[INFO]   } else {
[INFO]     ((SimpleCreationalContext) rootContext).finish();
[INFO]     this.finishInit();
[INFO]   }
[INFO] } catch (Throwable t) {
[INFO]   t.printStackTrace();
[INFO]   throw new RuntimeException("critical error in IOC container bootstrap: " + t.getClass().getName() + ": " + t.getMessage());
[INFO] }
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(45): {
[INFO]   try {
[INFO]     Container.init = false;
[INFO]     QualifierUtil.initFromFactoryProvider(new Container$1(this));
[INFO]     LogUtil.log("IOC bootstrapper successfully initialized.");
[INFO]     if (((IOCEnvironment) new IOCEnvironmentImpl()).isAsync()) {
[INFO]       LogUtil.log("bean manager initialized in async mode.");
[INFO]     }
[INFO]     final Bootstrapper bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class);
[INFO]     Container.injectionContext = bootstrapper.bootstrapContainer();
[INFO]     final CreationalContext rootContext = Container.injectionContext.getRootContext();
[INFO]     if (rootContext instanceof AsyncCreationalContext) {
[INFO]       ((AsyncCreationalContext) rootContext).finish(new Container$2(this));
[INFO]     } else {
[INFO]       ((SimpleCreationalContext) rootContext).finish();
[INFO]       this.finishInit();
[INFO]     }
[INFO]   } catch (Throwable t) {
[INFO]     t.printStackTrace();
[INFO]     throw new RuntimeException("critical error in IOC container bootstrap: " + t.getClass().getName() + ": " + t.getMessage());
[INFO]   }
[INFO] }
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(45): {
[INFO]   try {
[INFO]     Container.init = false;
[INFO]     QualifierUtil.initFromFactoryProvider(new Container$1(this));
[INFO]     LogUtil.log("IOC bootstrapper successfully initialized.");
[INFO]     if (((IOCEnvironment) new IOCEnvironmentImpl()).isAsync()) {
[INFO]       LogUtil.log("bean manager initialized in async mode.");
[INFO]     }
[INFO]     final Bootstrapper bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper) GWT.create(Bootstrapper.class);
[INFO]     Container.injectionContext = bootstrapper.bootstrapContainer();
[INFO]     final CreationalContext rootContext = Container.injectionContext.getRootContext();
[INFO]     if (rootContext instanceof AsyncCreationalContext) {
[INFO]       ((AsyncCreationalContext) rootContext).finish(new Container$2(this));
[INFO]     } else {
[INFO]       ((SimpleCreationalContext) rootContext).finish();
[INFO]       this.finishInit();
[INFO]     }
[INFO]   } catch (Throwable t) {
[INFO]     t.printStackTrace();
[INFO]     throw new RuntimeException("critical error in IOC container bootstrap: " + t.getClass().getName() + ": " + t.getMessage());
[INFO]   }
[INFO] }
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Container.java(45): public void bootstrapContainer();
```

Removing all inherited modules I created worked, the code compiled and worked fine. [I don't know why/how??]

On another different module, that also depends on other modules, if I `inherit` the dependency modules I created and get the exception above,  but If I remove these dependencies, I get the following error:

```
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/Projects/Fusion/UI/modules/preAuthorisation/target/classes/module/ui/widget/desktop/client/DesktopApp.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type modules.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I can see from the exception that this is because Errai is not creating the file `org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl` hence the `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl`. Can some one please help me explain why this is so? How can I solve this? All other modules compiles fine with no error.

Answer (score 0):

This NoClassDefFoundError on BootstrapperImpl is the standard error of something that was not able to be compiled to Javascript.

The root cause is (well) hidden somewhere in your stacktrace:

```
field org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField:module.ui.widget.shell.client.presenter.ShellPresenter.shellView could not be satisfied for type: module.ui.widget.shell.client.view.ShellView
```

Without the code of your classes, it's impossible to say exactly what is the problem.

But if I need to do a guess I would interpret this as: *inside your class ShellPresenter, there is a field named ShellView that has an issue.* It may be not able to create it, inject it or it's not GWT compatible, among possible reasons why.